# Switch statement does not seem to fall through

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this block of code which is based on the simpleweather.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var conditionsImageClass;
    $.simpleWeather({
        location: 'Leon, Spain',
        woeid: '',
        unit: 'f',

    success: function(weather) {
        switch(weather.code) {
            case 27:
                conditionsImageClass = '.diw-clouds:before';
                break;
            case 28:
                conditionsImageClass = '.diw-clouds-moon:before';
                break;
            default:
                conditionsImageClass = '.test'
                break;
        }

        alert(weather.code);
        alert(conditionsImageClass);

        var loc =   '<h5>'+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</h5>';
        html = '<p>Today</p><p><strong>'+returnsDate()+'</strong></p>';
        html += '<i class="' + conditionsImageClass + '"></i>';
        html += '<h2><strong><i class="icon-'+weather.code+'"></i> '+weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp+'</strong></h2>';
        html += '<h5 class="currently">'+weather.currently+'</h5>';
        $("#location").html(loc);
        $("#weather").html(html);

    },
    error: function(error) {
      $("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
    }
  });
});
```

Right now the switch statement doesn't seem to be executing. I haven't fully fleshed it out because I wanted to test it on the current conditions. Right now, the condition code for Leon is '28' or mostly cloudy. But the switch statement always defaults even though there is a case for '28'. Any ideas why it is doing that? Let me know if you need any more code.

Comment: I'm guessing weather.code is returning a string. You need to parse it first

Comment: debugging.... `console.log(weather)` at the least...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use **location: 'Leon, Spain',** + **woeid: '',** together.
In order to identify a location you can use a valid field, in your case location.

```js
$.simpleWeather({
    location: 'Leon, Spain',
    unit: 'f',
    success: function(weather) {
        console.log('weather.code is: ' + weather.code);
        switch(weather.code) {
            case '27':
                conditionsImageClass = '.diw-clouds:before';
                break;
            case '28':
                conditionsImageClass = '.diw-clouds-moon:before';
                break;
            default:
                conditionsImageClass = '.test'
                break;
        }
        console.log('conditionsImageClass is: ' + conditionsImageClass);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.simpleWeather/3.1.0/jquery.simpleWeather.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Using location, how does it actually get a location?

Comment: @pmath325 From [doc](http://simpleweatherjs.com/): You simply provide your US zip code, WOEID, lat/long, or any location in the world. When I tested using also your empty WOEID parameter I got error.

Answer (score -1):

`weather.code` is likely a string. Your cases are checking for integers and therefore they do not match. You need to parse the weather code using `parseInt()`, or turn each case into a string.

```
switch(parseInt(weather.code)) {
    case 27:
        conditionsImageClass = '.diw-clouds:before';
        break;
    case 28:
        conditionsImageClass = '.diw-clouds-moon:before';
        break;
    default:
        conditionsImageClass = '.test';
}
```

**A simplified example showing the difference**

```js
console.log(displayWeatherCode(27)); // "27!"
console.log(displayWeatherCode("27")); // "Default!"

function displayWeatherCode(weatherCode) {
    switch(weatherCode) {
        case 27:
            return "27!";
        case 28:
            return "28!";
        default:
            return "Default!";
    }
}
```